# Kick users out of an application

Tags: c#, winforms

I have written an application that is used company wide. A lot of users have the tendency to leave the application open 24-7. This application is under development constantly as the Marketing department's needs change. Most changes are minor but often times need to be implemented quickly. Salesmen are often away from their desks or on the phone, so an intercom announcement does not always do the trick. The application is housed on a network file share and shortcutted to.

What I envision is something like a message popping up something like "The program will exit for an update in five minutes, please save your changes now." Is there a way to display this message and kick them from the exe remotely? I thought of maybe just having a database value that it checks periodically to see if an update is pending, but that seems like a cheap hack to me.

Comment: You should consider making the app into a web app.

Comment: Do you use click once deployment? Your app could check for updates every X hours, then update and restart the app.

Comment: since this is an app "that shouldnt be too easy " to change app to web.

Comment: @0A0D: Yes, but kind of drastic wouldn't you say?

Comment: @Yuck: No. He obviously has a resource that is shared amongst multiple departments. If it is C#, it's trivial to convert an ASP.NET application.

Comment: @0A0D: it is very much **NON** -trivial to convert a WinForms or WPF app to ASP.NET. Yes, web apps are typically best for shared enterprise situations, but making a change like that is a huge undertaking.

Comment: Yeah it will be a huge task to convert it now

Comment: Why did I get a downvote? This seems like a pretty legitimate question

Comment: I'm voting to close this. It's a programming question and should never have been sent here.

Comment: Agreed with John. The guy wrote an app, and wants to add a feature. This is a programming question, not a sysadmin question.

Comment: @Nick I merged the migrated question back into your original question, reopened it and cleared out all the migration history. The question is now back under your control. Best of luck :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your database check is as good as any other; I personally would recommend polling some service to which it subscribes that would do the same thing. If your app connects directly to the database, however, you're probably better off making the check in the database.

You'd be best off going with a [ClickOnce](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t71a733d.aspx) deployment method, however. That would require a major architectural change, but would be best in the long run, IMO.

Comment: It is essentially a products database management application at it's heart, so it definitely hits the db directly.

Comment: @Nick: Then your initial idea is probably the best for your situation. It's not the best for *every* situation, but in your unique case, I say go with it. If you can swing the extra time necessary to change deployment scenarios to ClickOnce, you'll be better off later, but that's a political decision that could take some peading and/or arm-twisting to get done.

Answer (score 1):

Pity it's not a web application.  Deployment would be a snap!

Anyhow what I'd do is this.  Make the application log users out after several minutes of inactivity.

Two approaches to unsaved work.  Do nothing and therefore they loose it if unsaved when they are inactive and it logs them out.

As they work, a local journal of changes is kept.  When they are logged out due to inactivity, logging back will use the journal to open things back up as they were.

EDIT: To prevent users from using the old version. Write a database field with a version or build number.  If running version < version in db field then refuse login, and/or restart program to load new image.

Comment: I like the idea of logging them out after a period of inactivity. That really wouldn't be too intrusive in this situation as only a select few of the users will actually be modifying data in the program, the rest just pull reports and so forth. I can set it to something ridiculous like 5 hours of inactivity, that way it will get an update during the night some time. I still need a way to stop them immediately from using the program so this isn't quite the answer I'm looking for but +1 for a helpful suggestion thanks.

Comment: @Nick - see edited answer to stop users from using the program once an update has occurred.

Answer (score 0):

You can set up a central server that the .exe sends requests to to find out when updates are available.

I would recommend that you look into WCF as a framework for your solution; there are many great references for the framework as well as posts on sites like this one.  You can probably spin up a separate thread in your application that checks for updates every X minutes.

As for your specific question, "Is there way to display this message and kick them from the exe remotely?", yes it is possible, but it is more feasible to make the program automatically query for the update.

If you want to shut them down for update remotely, then you have to know where they are on the network.  If the program periodically contacts a central database, then there is no need for the server to know where the program is on the network, the program can automatically reach out to the server from wherever it is.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a messaging system such as RabbitMQ, or any other one, and have the applications listen to a channel in the system.  Then an administrative application could send a message to the user applications forcing them to shut down.

If the changes aren't breaking changes, you might want to look at something like ClickOnce which allows you to publish updates to applications while the users are running them, though users will be running old versions of the application until it restarts.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't get what you got stuck on. Just create a timer, and on user interaction, reset the timer, to e.g. 5 minutes. Then, when the timer fires, show the message box, and create another timer, when that one fires, just kill the current process.

Answer (score 0):

Rather tangential answer but if the issue is people leaving workstations up and logged on then take a look at something like nightwatchman from www.1e.com that powers down the PC after x period of inactivity.  Sell it to your company as "doing your bit for the environment" and saving wasted electricity costs.